# Session state not maintained when integrating ASP.NET MVC application as a iframe in application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iframe, session-state

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application which is the main application with tabbed control and each of the tabbed control displays an iframe meaning other asp.net web application are being rendered inside the iframe content in each tab.

Now we have a new ASP.NET MVC framework application which also needs to be integrated inside the asp.net main app as another tabbed control, while performing the integration in the new ASP.NET MVC session state is not getting maintained i.e. for each of the controller change, session start is getting invoked.

Can anyone please suggest how to maintain session state b/w these apps?

Note: I am using sessionstate of inproc type which works fine for all the other existing integrated apps.

I have tried using session state with samecookie=none, which didn't help..

The below is the config available for the existing application which works fine

```
<sessionState timeout="120" mode="InProc" />
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="oec" namespace="myapp.Application.Suites.Web.Controls" assembly="myapp.Application.Suites.Web" />
    </controls>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="myapp.Dealer.Web.Services.Utilities" />
        <add namespace="myapp.Application.Suites.Web.Extensions" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".SuitesAuth" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" loginUrl="http://example.com/default/sessionexpired" defaultUrl="~/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="720" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="ApplicationMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="ApplicationMembershipProvider" type="myapp.Application.Core.Web.ApplicationMembershipProvider, myapp.Application.Core.Web" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<!--  Uncomment this to share cookies with other Suites apps, won't work for standalone/localhost development. -->
<httpCookies domain=".mysite.com" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

The below is the config for the ASP.NET MVC app which doesn't work:

```
<sessionState  cookieSameSite="None" mode="InProc">
</sessionState>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".SuitesAuth" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" loginUrl="http://example.com/default/sessionexpired" defaultUrl="~/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="720" />
</authentication>`
```

Comment: If both applications are hosted on the same domain or subdomain, is it possible to consider using a centralized session store (such as a shared database or cache).

Comment: Yes both apps are hosted in same domain, is there a possibility to use cache for centralized session, please advice..

Comment: You can resort centralized session store or cache to maintain session state across applications. This approach allows you to share session data between multiple applications running on the same domain. A common way to do this is to use a distributed caching system such as Redis. Or use a database-based session store, which, while not as performant as an in-memory cache, provides a centralized storage mechanism for session data.